# Enable Usb device for remote debugging not working on firefox

Tags: debugging, firefox, usb, remote-debugging

The firefox version im using is 106.0.2.
Im trying to connect an oculus quest 2 for debugging a website project.

The problem is i press the enable usb devices button, it shows an updating status and then shows the same button again, the status remains disabled.
any ideas?

also chrome's dev tools didnt work, shows my device but doesnt show the tabs hence i went to firefox.

Tried restarting, resetting adb, checking if adb works on cmd, nothing worked.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem trying to set up debugging for Firefox on Android.

Comment: i managed to get chrome dev tools to work and im using that now, firefox was disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is clicked in Firefox, it attempts to download and install an extension, but the URL is malformed and the request is denied with a 404, which you can see using the Firefox console (not devtools). I filed a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1800786).

You can bypass the button and enable Firefox debugging by downloading and installing the extension via drag-and-drop from the correct URL, which I determined to be https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/labs/devtools/adb-extension/linux64/adb-extension-latest-linux64.xpi