# Problem Enabling USB Devices in Firefox for Remote Debugging on Android

Tags: android, firefox, adb, remote-debugging

I'm setting up for remote debugging a webpage in Firefox on Android. adb recognizes my device, but my device won't display in Firefix's `about:debugging#/setup` page. Instead, it says "USB disabled" and gives me a button called "Enable USB Devices" that is supposed to "download and add the required Android USB debugging components to Firefox". Pressing that button displays "Updating..." for a second, then reverts back to it's former state; subsequent presses flicker between states too fast to see.

I admit to opening a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1800786), but I don't even know if it's a bug since the button isn't documented in the [debugging guide](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/about_colon_debugging/index.html#connecting-to-a-remote-device) and the only mention of it on the web I can find is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235608/enable-usb-device-for-remote-debugging-not-working-on-firefox) that no one even commented on.

Does this button do anything for anyone? Am I supposed to be running a specific version of Firefox or OS or something? I'm running the latest version of FF (106.0.5).

Comment: Just making sure this isn't similar to: [Chrome://inspect#devices could not find devices for USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72536954/295004)

Comment: As I understand the instructions in the debugging guide (link above), Firefox's remote debugging actually relies on adb. My issue isn't with discovery though, it's enabling the interface in FireFox in the first place.

Comment: Does the button work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem using the Firefox console. The browser was making a request to the wrong URL, and getting a 404. I.e. this is a Firefox bug.

Spot the difference:

```
Broken : https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/devtools/adb-extension/linux64/adb-extension-latest-linux64.xpi
Correct: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/labs/devtools/adb-extension/linux64/adb-extension-latest-linux64.xpi
```

I filed a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1800786).